# Reverse enginnering SQL Server "decimal" type to a Java type in a Grails application

Tags: sql-server, grails, grails-orm

I am trying to use a legacy database on a grails application.

I created a new project and used the grails plugin [DB reverse engineer](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-db-reverse-engineer)

However I am having some issues.

One of them is that the legacy SQL Server database has a table with a column of type `decimal`, and I wasn't able to find any Java type that mapped to this one.

My attempts were:

```
Java Type  = SQL Server Type
Float      = float
Double     = double precision
Short      = smallint
Integer    = int
Long       = numeric(19, 0)
BigDecimal = numeric(19, 2)
BigInteger = numeric(19, 2)
```

Another issue is that the java type *String* isn't being correctly mapped to `char(X)` where *X* is the maxSize of the *String*.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the `decimal` type and `char(x)` type are there because of how old the database is, but they aren't really used nowadays.

The solution was simply to use an Hibernate Dialect as old as the database. In my case it was `org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseDialect`.

I set the dialect on *Datasource.groovy*